# Why can `for in` not split string directly in bash?

Tags: bash, quoting

For example:

```
# case 1
for i in "a b c"; do echo -n $i| od -b; done
# case 2
v="a b c"; for i in $v; do echo -n $i| od -b; done
```

Output:

```
0000000 141 040 142 040 143
0000005
0000000 141
0000001
0000000 142
0000001
0000000 143
0000001
```

Why can `for in` not split string directly in bash? What is the difference between case 1 and case 2?

Comment: Why would you *want* it to? That would mean you couldn't iterate over an array of strings without splitting them; that would be awful.

Comment: ...that said, string-splitting *in general* is awful, and well-written programs don't use it.

Comment: That said, `echo -n` is *also* awful -- see the [relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which explicitly suggests using `printf` instead (see APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections in particular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word splitting is a feature in unquoted parameter expansion (as well as unquoted command expansion). It's not a feature of `for` loops.

- Unquoted variables split strings in for loops because unquoted variables split strings (almost) everywhere.
- `for` loops don't split strings directly because they don't split strings at all. It's not the loop's responsibility.

Here's three examples, each with a literal string, a quoted variable and an unquoted variable. You can see that there are no special cases, all splitting is due to unquoted parameter expansion:

```
var="a b c"

command "a b c" "$var" $var
                        ^-- Only thing that splits

array=("a b c" "$var" $var)
                        ^-- Only thing that splits

for s in "a b c" "$var" $var
do ...                  ^-- Only thing that splits
```

Answer (score 4):

If `for` loops automatically performed string splitting, this would mean the following code would be impossible:

```
# this should be (and currently is!) two lines, not four.
for message in "hello world" "goodbye world"; do
  echo "$message"
done
```

or, for a slightly more real-world example, consider:

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo "Listing length in lines of files with spaces in their names from My Documents"
for file in "My Documents"/*; do
  printf '%s\t%s lines\n' "$file" "$(wc -l <"$file")"
done
echo "Done"
```

...in which case a `for` loop that did string splitting would treat `My` as a separate filename, rather than holding the filenames together.

---

If you want to **safely** split a string into multiple elements, use `read -a`, not string splitting:

```
v='a b c'
read -r -a v_a <<<"$v"
for i in "${v_a[@]}"; do
  printf '%s' "$i" | od -b
done
```

This will work correctly even for input values that string-splitting would munge -- consider `v='*'`, for instance, where string-splitting would replace the `*` character with a list of files in the current directory.